# Prepare data before NLog send it to target?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I need to serialize some objects before NLog sends it to its targets. I could write custom a target, but then I will have to write a custom target for each possible log target.

What I need to know is if NLog will be logging the message(based on the level) to any target and if so, serialize the data. If the logdata states a level that is not to be logged according to the NLog configuration, then I want to avoid serializing the objects because this takes time.

Is there any way to prepare data before NLog sends it to targets or will I have to solve this in custom target classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a [`Logger`](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/T_NLog_Logger.htm) and check the `IsXXXEnabled` property.

For example:

```
class MyExpensiveClass
{
    public void string Serialize()
    {
         return SomethingExpensive;
    }
}

class ThisNeedsLogging
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private MyExpensiveClass expensive = new MyExpensiveClass();

    public void TraceSomething()
    {
        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
            logger.Debug(expensive.Serialize());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great! So if any of the logger in the NLog.config is set to Debug or Trace the IsDebugEnabled will return true? For example 

<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeto="customTarget"></logger>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console"></logger>

Comment: Correct! If you configure your logger to `Trace`, and you check for `IsDebugEnabled`, you'll get `true`. If you configure it to `Info`, it will be `false`.
See [LogLevel](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/T_NLog_LogLevel.htm).